# Is it necessary to sink unneeded streams into a fakesink?

Tags: gstreamer

Suppose I have a GStreamer pipeline with a source that provides both audio and video and I am interested in only one of those. Can I ignore the other or is it best practice to route the unneeded stream into a `fakesink`?

Comment: Just leave the pad unconnected.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch this seems to work, but `fakesink` probably exists for a reason, right? Perhaps leaving the pad unconnected leaks memory?

Comment: `fakesinks` can be useful for testing, statistics, custom pad probes etc. If you do now want the data, do not connect anything. It saves processing power. (E.g. imagine an MP4 file with 100 different language audio tracks). No one wants to connect 99 `fakesinks` to that.